# how to only compile python module in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to add wrapping to some additional OpenCV functions, so how can compile only the python module without compiling the whole library, which takes a long time.

I figure out the steps from CMakeLists.txt and the Makefile generated by cmake, it should take three steps:

1. generate c++ header files (working!)

   python src2/gen.py src2/
   python src2/gen2.py . \
       ../core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp \
       ../flann/include/opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp \
       ../imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp \
       ../video/include/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp \
       ../video/include/opencv2/video/tracking.hpp \
       ../photo/include/opencv2/photo/photo.hpp \
       ../highgui/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp \
       ../ml/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp \
       ../features2d/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp \
       ../calib3d/include/opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp \
       ../objdetect/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp \
       ../contrib/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp \
       ../nonfree/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp \
       ../nonfree/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp
2. compile src2/cv2.cpp (not working!)

   g++ -fPIC -c src2/cv2.cpp -o cv2.o -DPYTHON_USE_NUMPY=1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs python opencv` -I /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/ -I .
3. linking (from Makefile, should working!)

   /usr/bin/c++  -fPIC    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-unused-function -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG   -shared -Wl,-soname,cv2.so -o ../../lib/cv2.so CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o -lpython2.7 ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_nonfree.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_video.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_contrib.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_legacy.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_softcascade.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_nonfree.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_features2d.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_flann.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_video.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_ml.so.3.0.0 ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0 -Wl,-rpath,/home/taowei/Src/opencv/lib:

So how can I correctly compile cv2.cpp in the step 2?

Comment: you forgot to mention the error.

Comment: src2/cv2.cpp:106:9: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
 typedef vector<uchar> vector_uchar;
         ^
src2/cv2.cpp:107:9: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
 typedef vector<int> vector_int;
         ^
src2/cv2.cpp:108:9: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
 typedef vector<float> vector_float;
         ^
src2/cv2.cpp:109:9: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
 typedef vector<double> vector_double;
         ^
src2/cv2.cpp:110:9: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
 typedef vector<Point> vector_Point;